# how to compare mmap and read performace

Tags: c, performance, mmap

I am trying to compare the performace of `mmap()` & `read()` for file sizes varying from 1KB to 1GB (increments in factor of 10).

The way I do it is I read the entire files (sequentially) and then write the output to another file for both the cases and measure the time.

**Code:**

For the `read()` code, I have:

```
 19         char text[1000];
. . . . . . 
 77         while((bytes_read=read(d_ifp,text,1000))>0)
 78         {
 79                 write(d_ofp, text, bytes_read);
 80         }
```

And for the `mmap()` code, I have:

```
 20         //char *data;
 21         uintmax_t *data;
 22         //int *data;
. . . . . . 
 86         if((data = (uintmax_t*)mmap((caddr_t)0, sbuf.st_size, PROT_READ, MAP_SHARED, fd, 0)) == (uintmax_t*)(-1))
 87         {
 88                 perror("mmap");
 89                 exit(1);
 90         }

 96         int j=0;
 97         while (i<=sbuf.st_size)
 98         {
 99                 fprintf(ofp, "data[%d]=%ju\n", i, data[j]);
101                 i=i+sizeof(*data);
102                 j++;
103         }
```

The calculated time in case of `mmap()` varies depending upon how I declare my `data` pointer (`char`, `int`, `uintmax_t`), whereas in case of `read()` it varies depending upon the size of buffer - `text`.

**Output:**
Right now `mmap` is proving to be really slow, which is surprising:

```
[read]:   f_size:    1K B, Time:  8e-06 seconds
[read]:   f_size:   10K B, Time:  1.4e-05 seconds
[read]:   f_size:  100K B, Time:  8.3e-05 seconds
[read]:   f_size:    1M B, Time:  0.000612 seconds
[read]:   f_size:   10M B, Time:  0.009652 seconds
[read]:   f_size:  100M B, Time:  0.12094 seconds
[read]:   f_size:    1G B, Time:  6.5787 seconds

[mmap]:    f_size:    1K B, Time:  0.002922 seconds
[mmap]:    f_size:   10K B, Time:  0.004116 seconds
[mmap]:    f_size:  100K B, Time:  0.020122 seconds
[mmap]:    f_size:    1M B, Time:  0.22538 seconds
[mmap]:    f_size:   10M B, Time:  2.2079 seconds
[mmap]:    f_size:  100M B, Time:  22.691 seconds
[mmap]:    f_size:    1G B, Time:  276.36 seconds
```

**Question:**
 1. If I take the buffer size in `read` code equal to the type size in `mmap` code, will the evaluation be correct/justified ?
 2. What is the right way to compare these two ?

**Edit:**

I changed the `fprintf` in `mmap` code to `write`, now the performance is way better but is very weird, it is decreasing for larger file sizes. Is that something expected ?
(I am writing my data to `/dev/null` in both the cases):

```
[mmap]:    f_size:    1K B, Time:  3.3e-05 seconds
[mmap]:    f_size:   10K B, Time:  2e-06 seconds
[mmap]:    f_size:  100K B, Time:  2e-06 seconds
[mmap]:    f_size:    1M B, Time:  4e-06 seconds
[mmap]:    f_size:   10M B, Time:  3e-06 seconds
[mmap]:    f_size:  100M B, Time:  2e-06 seconds
[mmap]:    f_size:    1G B, Time:  2e-06 seconds
```

Comment: Am i write in seeing that your read code is using write() to write out the data whereas the mmap version is using fprintf?

Comment: @FrederickCheung Best bet.

Comment: Yes. I am of the opinion to not use `write` for `mmap`. I might be wrong, just not sure.

Comment: @brokenfoot Right. If you are trying to benchmark things, **WHY** are you using a different write method in the second test ?

Comment: Because IMO it wont be a comparison otherwise if I use `write` for `mmap`, trying to keep them separate.

Comment: @cnicutar: Also, when we compare `read` vs `mmap`, doesn't it become `read/write` vs `mmap` ?

Comment: You should completely remove the output stage, since that's not what you want to test. Compute an MD5 checksum or something of all the bytes in the file, then stop the clock and print the checksum. Having totally different output paths (with *more I/O*) will completely skew any results.

Comment: @unwind: I am also trying to see the performance difference when it comes to writing to the file.

Comment: @cnicutar: I added an update after replacing `fprintf` with `write`. Please comment on it.

Answer (score 3):

This is somewhat speculation because I probably haven't thought of all the implications:

---

In the first case the majority of the time is taken by:

- Overhead of performing `read(2)` system calls (many of them)

  - Copying the data from one file to memory accessible by the process. The time is dominated by actually reading from the device (spinning the HDD or whatever)
- Performing `write(2)` system calls that don't take any time beyond syscall overhead (see below)

---

In the second case the majority of the time is taken by:

- Overhead of performing a single system call (one `mmap`). **This does not actually read anything**. The kernel just checks you have permissions and pretends to "map" the data.

  - Once you start doing something to it - like reading or writing - the kernel will actually map it in memory which will take time (*pagefaults*)
- Overhead of performing `write(2)` system calls. I assume the you perform fewer `write` calls for a larger file

---

In [Linux writing to `/dev/null`](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/drivers/char/mem.c?v=3.0#L621) is implemented like this:

```
static ssize_t write_null(struct file *file, const char __user *buf,
    size_t count, loff_t *ppos)
{
    return count;
}
```

Which roughly means: "just tell the process we did it". Which means **the `mmap`ed memory is never touched -> the file is never read**. So every time you only incur the cost of performing a system call. So the fewer `write`s you do, the less time you waste in interrupts that don't do anything anyway.

In conclusion, in both cases `write`s are cheap, no-op calls. But **in the first one the `read` actually costs** because data must actually be pulled from a file.

---

#### What about the `printf` case ?

In that case you were actively touching the memory `mmap`ed, thus forcing the kernel to stop lying and to actually read the data from the file. In addition to that you also printed it, which depending on the buffering `stdio` was using, was also triggering system calls from time to time. Just in case you were writing to the screen, this was especially costly since `stdout` is by default line-buffered.

Comment: This makes more sense. Thanks! Means, my `write`ing to `/dev/null` is doing nothing, so I guess this performance evaluation is justified since it is taking into account only the reads by `read` and `mmap` and the `write`s are behaving the same way for both.

Comment: @brokenfoot Well, remember. If you are not touching the data "read" by `mmap`, you are "cheating" because as detailed in the answer the kernel doesn't pull the data until it has to. I would suggest you walk the array and read from it every 4096 bytes (size of the page on your machine).

Comment: I overlooked that. Reading after every 4096 bytes will ensure every page is brought into the memory.